# French pack for Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, language, language-package

I am trying to install a French pack for my store and I am on Magento 1.8. The default language for my store is English.

And this is link of the French pack that I found,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-french-france-language-pack.html

But it does not work on my store.

Does this pack compatible with Magento 1.8?

What can I do to have a French version for my store if this pack does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the link you gave but check this out. https://web.archive.org/web/20140713085512/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/9

[Here is the French pack](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/9). It states that it's 99.5% complete so you won't have to do a lot of work.

My locale's translatios worked like a charm from the above link.

Cheers!

Comment: Also, in case you need to make specific translations for your theme and design, and you don't want to touch the core translation files, read a short tut i 've wrote recently. https://medium.com/@kbariotis/64b47377fc9

Comment: thanks. I got that file too and tried it already but it crashed my store. so then I follow this tutorial to install the French pack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wclpu44SjIA

Comment: btw, do you have instruction on how to install the zip from http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/9?

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Do you have an updated location maybee?

Answer (score 3):

please get the french language pack from

https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales

link

this working for 1.9